# Accidentally installed a system, how to completely remove it?

Tags: macos, carbon-copy-cloner

I made an error this weekend and am now not sure how to fix it.  I was cloning my boot hard drive (Sierra) to an image file on an external hard drive, using Carbon Copy Cloner.  No big deal, done it thousands of times before.  But this particular time, I bran farted and neglected to tell CCC to clone to an image file, instead selecting the external hard disk itself.  This means that CCC has cloned my entire boot system, onto the external drive where there is not supposed to be any bootable system.

I'd like to "undo" this, and somehow cleanly remove the entire OS and all its associated files, from the external drive, without impacting the rest of the drive's contents (so wiping the drive for example, is not an option).

Is there any efficient way to do this?  Is it just a matter of manually trashing all the system folders (and the associated invisible folders like /usr, /sbin, etc.) and emptying the trash?

Edit: Here is my `diskutil list` output:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Media Server            499.8 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *8.0 TB     disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Media1                  8.0 TB     disk1s2

/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *8.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS TM iMac                 8.0 TB     disk2s2
```

"Media1" is the external drive in question here, which now has all the files  it already had, plus a copy of the OS from "Media Server"

Edit 2:

```
total 45
drwxrwxr-x+ 51 root  admin  1734 Dec 22 21:03 Applications
drwxr-xr-x+ 61 root  wheel  2074 May 17  2018 Library
drwxr-xr-x@  2 root  wheel    68 Feb 20  2017 Network
drwxr-xr-x@  4 root  wheel   136 Dec 23 11:25 System
drwxr-xr-x   6 root  admin   204 Feb 11  2018 Users
drwxr-xr-x@  5 root  wheel   170 Jan  1 14:18 Volumes
drwxr-xr-x@ 38 root  wheel  1292 Dec 23 11:25 bin
dr-xr-xr-x   3 root  wheel  4324 Jan  1 13:40 dev
lrwxr-xr-x@  1 root  wheel    11 Feb 11  2018 etc -> private/etc
dr-xr-xr-x   2 root  wheel     1 Jan  1 13:47 home
-rw-r--r--@  1 root  wheel   313 Dec 21  2016 installer.failurerequests
dr-xr-xr-x   2 root  wheel     1 Jan  1 13:47 net
drwxr-xr-x@  6 root  wheel   204 Feb 11  2018 private
drwxr-xr-x@ 63 root  wheel  2142 Dec 23 11:25 sbin
lrwxr-xr-x@  1 root  wheel    11 Feb 11  2018 tmp -> private/tmp
drwxr-xr-x@ 10 root  wheel   340 May 17  2018 usr
lrwxr-xr-x@  1 root  wheel    11 Feb 11  2018 var -> private/var
```

Comment: I would just clone it "back" to your Mac, but this time do a file as you intended.  Then wipe the drive and write the image file back to it.

Comment: You lost me there.  The issue is that the external drive has a zillion files on it, and also now has a system folder installed that I don't want there.  Wiping the external drive is simply not an option because I would then have to do a massive multi-terabyte restore from backup and I really don't want to do that.

Comment: If you cloned your boot drive to your external disk, it *overwrote* the files that were existing on there.  Just to confirm, are you able to access those files (the ones prior to the overwriting)?

Comment: No that's the thing, it did not overwrite anything.  It merely added a clone of my boot drive TO the external disk.  Which frankly I was a little surprised at (and very relieved too!) . Yes I can access everything, the external drive is perfectly intact, it just has this extra system on it now.

Comment: Adding it to the question now...

Comment: A couple of things... can you tell me through which path you access these existing files and can you post the output of `ls -l /`

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "what path", I just access them from the Finder or any other application like any normal external drive that contains documents.  Updating with that output now...

Comment: I'd backup the drive.  How much of a prefectionist are you? I'd just delete what folders you do not want.  I don't understand why everything is owned by root wheel.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was going to do . I mean worst case, that system would no longer be bootable - but I don't want it there anyway so I wouldn't care.  And the drive is already backed up, I just don't want to have to do a massive lengthy restore if I don't actually need to.  And I'm probably around 75% perfectionist.  ;) . Thanks.

Comment: I don't know how ccc would do a copy.  Does it integrate all the files into duplicate folders?  I'd suggest asking over on the ccc forum.  Someone should have experience  ;-).

Comment: Yeah that one has me stumped as well.  It just copied the whole system onto the drive, without actually deleting anything that was already there.  Maybe that's a feature of CCC I'm unaware of and accidentally selected?  I dunno, but I'm very glad it didn't wipe the drive regardless!